# Navegação de Itens tipo <select> mobile

Tags: html, css, html5

Tenho um site responsivo com itens INPUT's e SELECT's, mas pela navegação do Chrome Android , pela tecla GO KEY do teclado virtual, quando estou com o foco em um item, e o próximo item da navegação é um tipo `<select>`, ele pula esse item e sempre vai para o próximo elemento do tipo INPUT.

Tem alguma forma de respeitar a sequencia de navegação do Desktop no mobile, e navegar pelos elementos `<select>`.

Att.

Comment: go key, vc se refere ao "next"?

Comment: Isso, a seta verde para a direita no canto do teclado.

Comment: Para entenderem o problema criei essa página  [link](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=69839:1)  , com um input , um select, outro input e outro select... ao invés de navegar do primeiro input para o primeiro select, ele pula para o INPUT, mesmo usando o TABINDEX, acredito que é um comportamento padrão da interface mobile, mas não sei qual a alternativa para fazer com que o usuário respeite a sequencia de entrada do formulário.

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho um ambiente de teste aqui para poder ver o funcionamento dessa opção, mas as vezes pode funcionar ai com vc.

Vc pode forçar a ordem dos "`tabs`" entre os campos usando o `tabindex` tipo `tabindex="1"` `tabindex="2"` `tabindex="3"` etc. Mas como eu disso não tenho uma ambiente para fazer o teste, apesar disso acredito que deve funcionar no mobile.

Veja que:

> O atributo global `tabindex` indica se um elemento pode receber foco
>   de entrada (se ele é focável), se e em qual posição ele deve fazer
>   parte da navegação sequencial do teclado (geralmente com a tecla Tab,
>   daí seu nome).

Aqui tem a documentação da Mozilla sobre o `tabindex`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Exemplo prático para vc testar ver se funciona:

```html
<input tabindex="1" type="text" name="" id="">
<select tabindex="2">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input tabindex="3" type="text" name="" id="">
<select tabindex="4">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Isso aí, tava dando uma pesquisada para ver se o comportamento era o mesmo do tab

Comment: @LeandroAngelo eu imagino que seja. Eu só não tenho um ambiente para fazer o teste infelizmente. Mas é uma dica que as vezes pode resolver

Comment: De repente tem algum bug na subistuição do `<select>` para a UI nativa e ele não faz o focus, mas também não tenho como testar aqui

Comment: Minha principal dúvida mesmo é se quando vc faz o focus no `<select>` o próximo tab seria no primeiro `<option>` ou no próximo input... Vamos ver o auq o autor da pergunta  vai dizer  rss

Comment: Testei a alternativa do Tabindex, mas também não funcionou, montei um pagina com o código acima para testarem: [link](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=69839:1) Estou usando Celular Android , No celular ele pula do tabindex=1 para o tabindex=4 , que é o próximo INPUT.

Comment: @user125144 Cara infelizmente testei aqui com seu link e não rolou no meu Android. As dicas agora são procurar um Form de outro site que tenha um Select acessível pelo "avançar" e fazer uma engenharia reversa, ou então Bloquear os campos com JS e libera-los na ordem que vc desejar, indicando qual o próximo campo a ser preenchido entende.